# Can I get a callback / do I know when SQLite has created write-ahead log files? I want to chmod them

Tags: sqlite, posix, file-permissions, chmod, umask

I have an elevated process and I want to make sure the SQLite files that it creates are readable by other processes. For some reason `umask` doesn't seem to do what I want (set permissions of sqlite file created by process).

I'm using write-ahead logging, so `-wal` and `-shm` files are created in addition to the database file. I want all 3 to be chmodded correctly.

I wonder if it's possible to get in after the SQLite file is created and `chmod` it.

Possible approaches:

1. `touch` all 3 files before SQLite tries to create them, then chmod and hope the mask stays the same
2. Intercept when the files are created and `chmod` them.
3. Work out how to get `umask` to work for the process.
4. Mystery option four.

What's the best way to go?

Questions for approaches:

1. Will SQLite be OK with this?
2. Do we know when all 3 files are created? Is there some kind of callback I can give a function pointer to? Do we know if the same `wal` and `shm` files are around forever? Or are they deleted and re-created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can touch the database file before opening it. (When you use the `sqlite3` command-line tool to open a new file, but do nothing but `begin;` and `commit;`, SQLite itself will create a zero-sized file.)

If you want to intercept file operations, you can register your own [VFS](http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html).

The `-wal` and `-shm` files are created dynamically, but SQLite will give them the same permission bits as the main database file. The comments for `robust_open()` in `os_unix.c` say:

> If the file creation mode "m" is 0 then set it to the default for
>   SQLite.  The default is SQLITE_DEFAULT_FILE_PERMISSIONS (normally
>   0644) as modified by the system umask.  If m is not 0, then
>   make the file creation mode be exactly m ignoring the umask.
>
> The m parameter will be non-zero only when creating -wal, -journal,
>   and -shm files.  We want those files to have *exactly* the same
>   permissions as their original database, unadulterated by the umask.
>   In that way, if a database file is `-rw-rw-rw` or `-rw-rw-r-`, and a
>   transaction crashes and leaves behind hot journals, then any
>   process that is able to write to the database will also be able to
>   recover the hot journals.

Comment: Interesting. Can you give a reference for "SQLite will give them the same permission bits "?